# EmguCV Colour Recognition

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm trying to make a program to detect colours off of  a Rubiks cube [image]

thats the screenshot of what I have up and running so far, I basically used the code from the Edge Detection example that ships with emguCV and used that to detect the small cubes (but as you can see some of the small cubes arent being detected, but thats not the problem I want to discuss here).

Now after finding out WHERE the small cubes are, I want to detect which colour they are, currently I'm using the HSV values to decide the colour, like so:

```
if (current_colour.Hue > 120 && current_colour.Hue < 170)
{
     Colours[(int)colornames.W]++;
}
else if (current_colour.Hue > (170))
{
     Colours[(int)colornames.R]++;
}
else if (current_colour.Hue > 5 && current_colour.Hue < 20 )
{
     Colours[(int)colornames.O]++;
}
else if (current_colour.Hue > 47 && current_colour.Hue< 60)
{
     Colours[(int)colornames.G]++;
}
else if (current_colour.Hue > 15 && current_colour.Hue < 30)
{
     Colours[(int)colornames.Y]++;
}
else if (current_colour.Hue > 100 && current_colour.Hue < 110)
{
     Colours[(int)colornames.B]++;
}
```

where the values for each colour I got from trial and error using photoshop...I am sure there must be some better way as Im getting results that are jumbled up (especially with the white and red)
Any help?

Comment: Hi, are you using all the data within the square to produce an average colour or just an individual pixel the GetAverage will produce the average value for a ROI. To gain better results use the saturation and value. You could also use other image type such as Bgr to confirm results especially since white will be (255,255,255) and red (0,0,255) in an ideal world. May I also say what you doing looks really interesting nice work. Hope I can help

Comment: Hey Chris, I WAS using a single pixel, but now I'm thinking of taking the average of multiple (about 9 or 10) pixels within the square (by writing my own function) is GetAverareage a function that will do this for me (I googled it but found nothing).

Comment: Hi, yes it will all it does is take the ROI, add each pixel up and divide by the number of pixels so writing your own function is just as easy. I expect that a single pixel will be producing your main error as the black will effect the the colour if it's near the edge thanks to image encoding and compression never mind noise. I would suggest taking the squares centre and working from there. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, I  wrote my own function to average the value over 10 different sample points and it certainly helps a lot, now all Ive got to do is fix the square recognition (edge tracing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your image is as simple as your example, You can do a histogram on the image.  The peaks in your histogram will correspond to the colors you use.

So you'd have to make a histogram or three, take the highest 10 (or whatever) bin values that are significantly far enough away from each other, and there you have your colors.